# Need a jQuery Form Deserializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization, forms

Does anyone know the best way to deserialize a form with a json object in jQuery?  I see there are a couple plugins out there, but was wondering if anyone with experience in the area knows the best one or way to implement without a plugin.  Thanks!

Comment: "deserialize a form with a json object".  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Take an object of key/value pairs and fill in a form with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends a bit on the structure of your JSON input and the structure of your form, but a really straight forward implementation could look as follows: (assuming trusted input)

```
var form = $('#myForm');
$.each(inputValues, function(name, value) {
  form.find('*[name="' + name + '"]').val(value);
});
```